# How can I create a password using HTML?

Tags: html, forms, button, passwords, submit

This is what I have so far:

```
  <form method="POST">
<p>  Password: </p>
<input type="password" name="passcode">
<input type="submit" value="login">
 </form>
```

I need help on finding out how to make it so that if I click "login", it will go to another page (eg. index2.html), but only if the password is correct.

Please help!

Comment: do you need to do that client side check or need to check the password on the server side?

Comment: If you're asking for how a server can check passwords against a username for an existing user, you're going to need to use another language, like PHP, or an AJAX request over JS. HTML cannot check passwords for you against a list on a server.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking to do cannot be accomplished in pure HTML. Simple as that.

The other answers explain the building blocks for how to do this with a server-side scripting language such as PHP, which is likely the best way to move forward. In such a case, without changing page, you would need to use AJAX to post the data to another URL in order to return a response.

Alternatively if this is just for yourself you could do a clientside check with something like Javascript, but then your password/url could just be scraped off the page.

As you're not talking about checking whether the user is authorised once they reach the next page then this could be all you need for something very basic.

Answer (score 0):

As you're submitting the form via `POST` method, you can access the form via the global `$_POST` array in PHP. It isn't best practice to access this array but it'll give you a good idea.

Also, I would recommend assigning a `name` attribute to your form, so you can access the form via `$_POST['formName']`

Comment: I believe the asker is asking how one can do a user login validation without moving the user to another page

Answer (score 0):

Use `<form action="other page url">`

The `action=""` attribute redirects the form to another page.

The `method="POST"` that you're using is only necessary if you are using PHP, so I don't think you need it for your case.

You could use some jQuery to check if the input field has certain text in it, and if so then redirect, if not then stay on the page and spit out some error message.

Ideally, you would want to use some server-sided language for this, such as PHP. Also, being that you are using passwords, you would also want to use a database to store the users information.